# How to create a Balloon Overlay on a MapView?

Tags: java, android, android-mapview, balloon

I need to create a balloon overlay from where a user long presses on the MapView.

Firstly how would i create the balloon overlay dynamically where the point was selected?

A user will long press on the MapView within the application and the gesture detector cathches the gesture.

I dont know how to go about creating a balloon overlay at the point that was selected. any ideas?

```
 mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLongPress(MotionEvent e) {
                Log.d(tag, "Long Press event");
                // i need to create a balloon at the point that was long pressed
            }
 }
```

i call this is in an overlay set on the map

```
mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing ballon on map usually you need to show pins on your map. On clicking that pin a ballon will appear. here is an example of how to do it.

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons